# How to get value of data from td in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have following html table where in I want to fetch data value of  using

```
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td data="1">Hello 1</td>
      <td data="2">Hello 2</td>
      <td data="3">Hello 3</td>
      <td data="4">Hello 4</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using nokogiri to read xpath of html as below

```
# Crawl a HTML elements using Nokogiri  
def crawlTableData()
  require 'open-uri' 
  require 'nokogiri' 
  open("http://localhost:/somepage",http_basic_authentication: ["username", "somepassword"]) do |f|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f.read) 
    return doc.xpath('//*[@id="main-panel"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text
  end  
end
```

So finally it return nothing to me.
can anyone suggest what is correct way to fetch data value of

Comment: There is no `tbody` in the HTML sample you give. Is it in the real HTML? Where did you get the XPath from (with `tbody`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one `<td>`(s) `data` attribute's value, use like

```
doc.at('//*[@id="main-panel"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')['data']
```

[at](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#at-instance_method) *search for the first occurrence of path. Returns nil if nothing is found, otherwise a Node.*

To get the attribute value for the attribute `name`, use [`[](name)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#%5B%5D-instance_method) method.